# Що означає слово пурец?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Сьогодні випадково почула розмову, в якій було згадане дещо дивне для мене слово:

> [...] ти диви, але то **пурец**!

Спочатку подумала, може то якась помилка, однак це слово було повторено декілька разів в дещо зневажливому значенні.

Мені закортіло дізнатися, що ж воно означає. Відкрила [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/purec), однак такого слова немає. Якщо звернутись у Google, вибиє одразу сорти перцю, де їх купити та Вікіпедію про слово перець. Отож що означає слово **пурец**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Також детальнішу інформацію про це слово знаходимо в [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm):

> [**пу́риц**] «зарозумілий парубок, чоловік» Гор<sup>*1*</sup>, [*пу́равец*] «шмаркач; молода недосвідчена людина» О<sup>*2*</sup>;
>
> - польська застаріле puryc «єврейський багач»;
> - запозичення з мови ідиш; порівняй ідиш puric (*пуріц*) «великий пан», гебрайська puric «зломщик», purica «погромник; хуліган». — Горбач 76.

---

> <sup>*1*</sup> *Горбач Ол.* Північно-наддністрянська говірка й діалектний словник с. Романів Львівської області. — Мюнхен, 1965. — 103 с.

> <sup>*2*</sup> *Онишкевич М. Й.* Словник бойківського діалекту [Рукопис. Опубліковані частини: Словарь бойковского диалекта [Буква Б]. — У кн.: «Славянская лексикография и лексикология». М., 1966. Словарь бойковского диалекта. [Буква К]. — У кн. «Карпатская диалектология и ономастика». М., 1972].

Answer (score 6):

[Лексикон львівський](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53407/1066304.html):

> **пурец**
>
> **пу́рец** (пу́рець, пу́риць) пихата людина (ст)

Для точнішого пошуку просто беріть "слово", яке шукаєте, в лапки або пишіть слово "словник" після того слова, яке шукаєте.

Answer (score 1):

Поріц (פוריץ) - я чув це слово на івриті у значенні "пан", "місцевий володар". Слово "пурец" ідишське, частенько чув від своїх батьків у тому ж значенні, що івритське "поріц", але дещо в іронічному контексті, на кшталт "теж мені великий пурец".

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди обґрунтовуйте свої відповіді посиланнями на поважні джерела. Суб'єктивні і необґрунтовані відповіді провокують суперечки і мінуси.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: О, фактично усне підтвердження [того, що написано в етимологічному словнику](/a/4624), дякуємо. (Але запитання: я правильно розумію, що відповідне слово в значенні «пан, місцевий володар» є і в ідиші, і в івриті? Чи лише в ідиші?)